# How to find out if CPU is ARM v5 cpu instructions compatible

Tags: cpu, backwards-compatibility, cpu-architecture

I would like to know how to identify whether or not a CPU is compatible with the ARM v5 Instruction Set.

And is it correct to assume that ARM v7 Instructions would be compatible with ARM v5?

Comment: arm5 is for the most part compatible with arm7, not the other way around.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply... got the following reply from the Marmalade forums:  [link](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/5295#comment-17435)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the [CPUID base register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337h/Cihhbddh.html) to get the PARTNO.  You can then use the value to [map](http://search.arm.com/search?site=Site-Search&entqr=0&output=xml_no_dtd&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&client=ARM_Site_Refresh&ud=1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&getfields=Description&proxystylesheet=ARM_Site_Refresh&q=CPUID%20base%20register) to the type of the processor and thus the instruction set it implements.